# How to perform case sensitive string comparision with simple.data

Tags: orm, simple.data

Is it possible to do case sensitive string comparison with Simple.Data? I want to validate username and password and need to make password comparison case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to do this using Simple.Data, the COLLATE keyword isn't supported (assuming you're using SQL Server).

That said, it sounds like you're "doing it wrong" regarding password handling. You should have a per-user "salt" value which you combine with the entered password in your hashing algorithm. So you need to `FindByUsername` the record and then verify the password in your application code. If you really need the user name to be case sensitive (which is unusual) then you can do that comparison in code, too.

Comment: Thanks Mark but I am just curious I don't want the username to be case sensitive but rather the password, is it unusual? Most of the sites have this feature where if my password is abc and I enter ABC they wont validate it.

Comment: Yes, passwords absolutely should be case-sensitive to increase complexity, but the comparison should never be done by the database, since you should have per-user hash salts for added security.